# Kivy: Shift+Tab does not work with TextInput

Tags: tabs, kivy, focus, textinput, shift

I am trying to cycle backwards through my TextInputs by hitting Shift+Tab (I know nothing special). And I just don't know how to get it to work. It always jumps to the next TextInput. I didn't find anything in Google.

Additionally, I want the whole TextInput.text to be selected, when focus=True. Didn't get that to work properly, either.

PLEASE, help me out :-D

Here is my minimal example btw:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<CustomInput@TextInput>:
    text: "Blindtext"
    size_hint_y: 0.1
    pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.5}
    multiline: False
    write_tab: False

<Box>:
    padding: 20,0,20,0
    spacing: 10

    CustomInput

    CustomInput

    CustomInput
''')

class Box(BoxLayout):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Box()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

Highly appreciated!
Cheers,
smarwin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with this post: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6560

You have to change the `if ['shift'] == modifiers:` line to `if modifiers == {'shift'}:` in the keyboard_on_key_down method of focus.py. You will find this file in your kivy folder in uix/behaviors/.

```
    def keyboard_on_key_down(self, window, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 'tab':  # deal with cycle
            if ['shift'] == modifiers: 
                next = self.get_focus_previous()
            else:
                next = self.get_focus_next()
            if next:
                self.focus = False

                next.focus = True

            return True
        return False
```

No guarantees, but it works fine for me so far.
Cheers,
smarwin

Answer (score 0):

Deleting characters(with backspace) stopped working for me with smarwin's workaround.

Calling super right before final `return False` fixed it for me.

E.g.

```
...
   next.focus = True

   return True
super().keyboard_on_key_down(window, keycode, text, modifiers)
return False
```

There was some info about it in [docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-1.11.1/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.focus.html#kivy.uix.behaviors.focus.FocusBehavior.keyboard_on_key_down)